# How to Globally Install ESLint with TypeScript-Support?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I would like to configure my GLOBAL eslint installation to lint my typescript project in Visual Studio Code.

So I installed the Visual Studio Code extension "ESLint" and installed ESLint with

```
npm install -g eslint
```

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin it is required to install `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` globally as well, so I ran

```
npm install -g @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
```

to install it together with the ts parse `@typescript-eslint/parser`.

Next, I added a very simple .eslintrc-file:

```
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": { }
}
```

However, as soon as I run `eslint .` in my project directoy I get:

```
Error: Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module '@typescript-eslint/parser'
```

Next I tried removing the globally installed parser and install it locally, yet this won't work neither: Now my *global* eslint installation can find my *local* parser, but the parser needs yet another *local* installation of typescript, eslint etc. I want to run everything globally, though.

I simply can't get it to work! Can anyone help me with the process?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions...

In your .eslintrc you haven't specified the '@typescript-eslint' plugin...

> "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],

Also, if you get this working you will also want to specify parserOptions.project & tsconfigRootDir with an absolute path because finding your tsconfig.json - so that you can use the rules that require type info - is harder from a global install.

Also, I think you need to explicitly tell the eslint plugin to validate your TS files (and maybe js and react etc., as desired) with vsc settings....

> ```
> "eslint.validate": [
>     "javascript",
>     "javascriptreact",
>     "typescript",
>     "typescriptreact"
> ],
> ```

BUT, I fear the whole thing is an uncertain undertaking.... note that [the docs say](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started)...

> It is also possible to install ESLint globally rather than locally
>   (using npm install eslint --global). However, this is not recommended,
>   and any plugins or shareable configs that you use must be installed
>   locally in either case.

I'm noting here that global installs are not recommended, but also that this quote seems to contradict the reference you noted that said to install the plugin globally.  I'm not sure which is right as I've stopped setting it up this way since it isn't recommended.  Hope this helps never-the-less.

Comment: Thanks Tom! Indeed, it seems that with ESLint 6.0.0 support for global installations and the typescript plugin is somewhat "broken". I tried a lot but simply couldn't get it to work. I went with a local installation now and everything looks fine. Thanks for your response anyway!